# Single Spring repository to produce different objects or entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have repository in my spring project:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    boolean existsById(long id);

    List<User> findAllByEmail(String email);

}
```

It works fine but appeared necessary to use `LightUser`

```
public class LightUser implements Identifiable<Long>, Auditable {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserType userType;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String domain;

    // get/set methods/ equals/hashcode
}
```

`LightUser` entity contains a few fields I need in general (all fields precent in `User` entity), and I want do request to DB using repository mapping results into `LightUser` (it would be really good to map into dto).

Is it possible add special method into `UserRepository` to cover my needs or i should create similar one for same table but for `LightUser`? If it possible, provide example please or core idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to remove `@Repository` annotation from your interface since it's redundant.

And yes, you can select into LightUser using two ways:

1) Projection

You have to create projection with needed properties:

```
interface LightUser {
    Long getId();
    String getEmail();
}
```

And add appropriate select method:

```
@Query("SELECT u.id AS id, u.email AS email FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id")
LightUser findLightUser(@Param("id") String id)
```

The disadvantage of this way is that your projection should be an interface (but if you use this for REST, it's OK)

2) DTO

Your DTO should have a constructor with needed fields, for instance, id and email:

```
class LightUser {
    private Long id;
    private String email;

    public LightUser(Long id, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

and then you can write a select for this DTO:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.test.LightUser(u.id, u.email) FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id")
LightUser findLightUser(@Param("id") String id)
```

Since your LightUser is like DTO, you have to use second way.

Answer (score 2):

`UserRepository` is a JPA repository that manages a `User` entity as mentioned in its definition `UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>`.

For a new entity `LightUser` its better to create a seperate repository `LightUserRepository` like so

```
@Repository
public interface LightUserRepository extends JpaRepository<LightUser, Long> {

    ....

}
```